# Gravity forms: change "Company" field to "Last Name, First Name" if left blank

Tags: field, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

I have a Gravity Form with the fields First Name, Last Name, and Company. I need the Company field to submit Last Name, First Name if someone doesn't fill out the Company field. What's the easiest possible way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I completely understand your question, but have you looked in the Advanced tab section? There should be a ‘Default Value’. Hovering over the question-mark will show you that you can use merge tags here to pre-populate the value of your field.

If this is not what you are looking for, please explain in a little more detail